# Can't assign normal keyboard shortcuts on Monterey because "it's already used by a system-wide keyboard shortcut"

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts-app, monterey

I just bought a new MacBook and it came with Monterey installed. Normally, I would set up "Cmd+\" to map to the 1Password Mini browser, to retrieve passwords. I also have shortcuts set up for [Divvy](https://mizage.com/divvy/) - "Cmd+E" brings up the Divvy window, and then "S" assigns the window to the left half of the screen, "F" to the right half, "R" to the top right corner, etc.

When I try to assign any of these shortcuts, I get a system dialog informing me that the shortcut I have tried to assign cannot be used because "it's already used by a system-wide shortcut."

I pulled up the Keyboard preferences and went to Shortcuts and scrolled the entire list and didn't see anything conflicting. I also opened the "Shortcuts" app but I do not have any shortcuts installed.

What do I need to do to get my keyboard shortcuts working again?

Comment: Right but the way Divvy works is, you press "cmd+E" to open the Divvy window, and then you can use a range of keys while Divvy is the frontmost app to move the next-front-most window to various positions on the screen. So you're not really pressing "Cmd+F", it's "Cmd+E", and then "F"

Comment: Right - that's not quite what I had set up before, I did not have to press cmd+F, just "F" while the application was focused (I did not use the Global Shortcut option.)

Comment: Testing in **macOS Big Sur** I was able to set single character non-global _keyboard shortcut_ in **Divvy** with the exact _keyboard shortcut_ you've mentioned. In an original install of **macOS Monterey** as your've found out, I too ran into the same issue. I installed it the same way on both systems using the same downloaded **Divvy.zip** _file_. Clearly **Apple** has change something in **macOS Monterey**. I'd suggestions you contact: [support@mizage.com](mailto:divvy@mizage.com?subject=Divvy%20Support%20Request) as it clearly does not perform as stated on their website.

Comment: That said, I did find a workaround if you have a backup of the `~/Library/Preferences/com.mizage.direct.Divvy.plist` _file_ from your previous system. I quit **Divvy**, then copied the target file from **macOS Big Sur** to **macOS Monterey** and rebooted. (You have to reboot.) I then had the single character non-global _keyboard shortcuts_ under **macOS Monterey**. The settings are stored in the `shortcuts` _key_ as **binary PLIST data**, so it's not easily manipulated.

Comment: It's too late now, however, tomorrow I'll examine the data structure closer and see if the settings can be manipulated to turn e.g **⌘S** to **S**, etc. until it's fixed by the developer, if you do not have a backup from the previous system.

Comment: The problem is that Monterey changed some shortcuts to use `fn` key combinations. For example `fn + f` is enter fullscreen, `fn + e` is show Emoji picker etc. For some reason when you try to assign those keys as a shortcut, it conflicts with those shortcuts even if you do not press the `fn` key.

Comment: @Mateusz Szlosek, RE: "The problem is that Monterey changed some shortcuts to use fn key combinations." -- As I said in one of my comments "**Apple** has change something in **macOS Monterey**." and your comment confirms that and what the change is. I have found the behavior in **Divvy** conflicting in that it will not allow one to choose the single character **F** for a non-global _keyboard shortcut_ as its assigned with **fn** to **Enter Full Screen**, however, even though **fn D** is assigned to **Start Dictation…**, nonetheless it allows the single character **D** to be assigned. Oh Well!

Comment: @user3439894 That's strange indeed. I've checked the plist and the `shortcuts` key and it seems it has an object that is encoded using `NSKeyedArchiver` so it will be very hard to manipulate it without knowing the Divvy sourcecode.

Comment: @Mateusz Szlosek, RE: "it will be very hard to manipulate it without knowing the Divvy sourcecode" --  The `shortcuts` _key_ is itself just embedded **binary PLIST** _data_ like any other **binary PLIST** _file_. I have already extracted and decoded the `shortcuts` _key_ and will shortly test editing and updating the _key_ with the changes, more so just for the fun of hacking it to see if it works. (I see no reason why it wouldn't.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The behavior your are seeing is consistent with changes **Apple** has made in **macOS Monterey**, as compared to **macOS Big Sur**, to its assigned *global system keyboard shortcuts* as mentioned in a comment by Mateusz Szlosek.

For example, the following *keyboard shortcuts* are a few that are new to **macOS Monterey**:

| Menu Item | Keyboard Shortcut |
| --- | --- |
| Start Dictation… | fn D |
| Emoji & Symbols | fn E |
| Enter Full Screen | fn F |

However, there is an inconstancy in what **macOS** reports when trying to assign a single character non-global *keyboard shortcut* in **Divvy**, in that while trying to assign, e.g., **S** or **F** it reports, e.g. for **S**, and the same for **F** (with it in its place appropriately).

> The key combination S can't be used!
>
> The key combination "S" can't be used because it's already used by a system-wide keyboard shortcut. (If you really want to use this key combination, most shortcuts can be changed in the Keyboard & Mouse panel in System Preferences.)

Yet it allows one to assign the single character non-global *keyboard shortcut* **D** even though its assigned to: **Start Dictation…**

Although there is a workaround, the following individual alpha characters and other characters, by default in **macOS Monterey**, can not be used as a single character *keyboard shortcut* when trying to assign one in **Divvy**:

**A   C   F   H   M   N   Q   S   `   \   ←   ↑   ↓   →**

### Solutions

- To resolve your issue the obvious answer is to use a different single character *keyboard shortcut*, as non-global, or use in conjunction with *modifier keys*.
- If possible, modify the existing *global system keyboard shortcuts* in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts** to free up the single character for use in **Divvy**.
- Another option is to restore the *preferences* for **Divvy** from a backup of the `~/Library/Preferences/com.mizage.direct.Divvy.plist` *file* from your previous system, which I have tested and it works. Note that in doing so one must first quit **Divvy**, restore the aforementioned `.plist` *file*, and one must reboot directly after restoring the *file*. (Yes, in this case, a reboot is required.)
- Yet another option is to edit the aforementioned `.plist` *file*, which I have in limited testing in a *virtual machine* been successful in doing.

---

### Editing com.mizage.direct.Divvy.plist

*This section of the answer is for proof of concept, and directions on how I made the example edit.*

The contents of the aforementioned `.plist` *file*, in its **XML Property List** format, with having set **⌘E** as the global *keyboard shortcut* to bring up **Divvy**, and no other setting changes, shows as:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>SULastCheckTime</key>
    <date>2021-11-08T13:02:01Z</date>
    <key>enableAcceleration</key>
    <true/>
    <key>globalHotkey</key>
    <dict>
        <key>keyCode</key>
        <integer>14</integer>
        <key>modifiers</key>
        <integer>256</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>useGlobalHotkey</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then with adding a single character non-global *keyboard shortcut* **L** assigned to **Left Half**, which consists of the left half of the screen in is default configuration, in its **XML Property List** format, it shows as:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>SULastCheckTime</key>
    <date>2021-11-08T13:03:32Z</date>
    <key>enableAcceleration</key>
    <true/>
    <key>globalHotkey</key>
    <dict>
        <key>keyCode</key>
        <integer>14</integer>
        <key>modifiers</key>
        <integer>256</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>shortcuts</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGBwpYJHZlcnNpb25ZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3BYJG9iamVjdHMS
    AAGGoF8QD05TS2V5ZWRBcmNoaXZlctEICVRyb290gAGmCwwSKSoxVSRudWxs0g0ODxFa
    TlMub2JqZWN0c1YkY2xhc3OhEIACgAXdExQVFhcOGBkaGxwdHh8gISIiJCUmHycoISFY
    c2l6ZVJvd3NfEA9zZWxlY3Rpb25FbmRSb3dfEBFzZWxlY3Rpb25TdGFydFJvd1pzdWJk
    aXZpZGVkVmdsb2JhbF8QEnNlbGVjdGlvbkVuZENvbHVtbldlbmFibGVkW3NpemVDb2x1
    bW5zV25hbWVLZXlca2V5Q29tYm9Db2RlXxAUc2VsZWN0aW9uU3RhcnRDb2x1bW5da2V5
    Q29tYm9GbGFncxAGEAUQAAgIgAQQAgmAAxAlWUxlZnQgSGFsZtIrLC0uWiRjbGFzc25h
    bWVYJGNsYXNzZXNYU2hvcnRjdXSiLzBYU2hvcnRjdXRYTlNPYmplY3TSKywyM15OU011
    dGFibGVBcnJheaMyNDVXTlNBcnJheVhOU09iamVjdAAIABEAGgAkACkAMgA3AEkATABR
    AFMAWgBgAGUAcAB3AHkAewB9AJgAoQCzAMcA0gDZAO4A9gECAQoBFwEuATwBPgFAAUIB
    QwFEAUYBSAFJAUsBTQFXAVwBZwFwAXkBfAGFAY4BkwGiAaYBrgAAAAAAAAIBAAAAAAAA
    ADYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG3
    </data>
    <key>useGlobalHotkey</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The settings for the user created *keyboard shortcuts* are stored in the `shortcuts` *key*, which is **binary PLIST data**, just like any other individual **binary PLIST** *file*, but embedded within. It is in this *data* that one can change the e.g. single character non-global *keyboard shortcut*, e.g., **L** to  **S**.

Extracted `shortcuts` *data* , in its **XML Property List** format, shows as:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>$archiver</key>
    <string>NSKeyedArchiver</string>
    <key>$objects</key>
    <array>
        <string>$null</string>
        <dict>
            <key>$class</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CF$UID</key>
                <integer>5</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>NS.objects</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>CF$UID</key>
                    <integer>2</integer>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>$class</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CF$UID</key>
                <integer>4</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>enabled</key>
            <true/>
            <key>global</key>
            <false/>
            <key>keyComboCode</key>
            <integer>37</integer>
            <key>keyComboFlags</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>nameKey</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CF$UID</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>selectionEndColumn</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>selectionEndRow</key>
            <integer>5</integer>
            <key>selectionStartColumn</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>selectionStartRow</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>sizeColumns</key>
            <integer>6</integer>
            <key>sizeRows</key>
            <integer>6</integer>
            <key>subdivided</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <string>Left Half</string>
        <dict>
            <key>$classes</key>
            <array>
                <string>Shortcut</string>
                <string>NSObject</string>
            </array>
            <key>$classname</key>
            <string>Shortcut</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>$classes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSMutableArray</string>
                <string>NSArray</string>
                <string>NSObject</string>
            </array>
            <key>$classname</key>
            <string>NSMutableArray</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>$top</key>
    <dict>
        <key>root</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CF$UID</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>$version</key>
    <integer>100000</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

To change the single character, e.g., **L** to **S** one would modify the `keyComboCode` *key* from `37` to `1`.    <sub>[List of Key Codes](https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes)</sub>

Setting aside any *third-party applications/utilities* that exist to manipulate **Property List Files**, and even **Apple**'s own **Xcode** as not everyone wants to install a 30+GB *application*, here are some of the **Apple** built-in *command line utilities* and *applications* that can to one degree or another work with **Property List Files**.

- `/usr/bin/defaults`
- `/usr/bin/plutil`
- `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`
- **Terminal**
- **Script Editor**
- **System Events**
- **TextEdit**
- Other native *command line utilities* that can be used in conjunction with the others mentioned.

Note: The following is not intended to offer a fully automated programatic solution to editing the target **binary PLIST** *file*, far from it, and is going to be a multi-step process to make the edit(s).

## Having quit Divvy...

### In **Terminal**

- Backup the existing target **binary PLIST** *file*.

```
cd ~/Library/Preferences/
cp -anv com.mizage.direct.Divvy.plist com.mizage.direct.Divvy.plist.bak
```

<sup>• Hint: Copy and paste the *commands* into **Terminal**, then press: <kbd>enter</kbd></sup>

### In **Script Editor**

- Create a new *document* and run the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* to create a *file* containing the *data* of the `shortcuts` *key*. Just copy and paste, then run it (**⌘R**). No editing necessary.
- This will create the *file* `~/divvy.shortcuts.plist` from the `shortcuts` *key* in the `~/Library/Preferences/com.mizage.direct.Divvy.plist` *file*. It is just a temporary *file* to make the edit(s) and update the `.plist` *file* used by **Davvy**, then is deleted.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
property bPlistFile : "com.mizage.direct.Divvy.plist"
property bPlistData : missing value
property thePropertyListFilePath : POSIX path of ¬
    ("" & (path to preferences from user domain) & bPlistFile)
property bPlistDataShortcuts : POSIX path of ¬
    ("" & (path to home folder) & "divvy.shortcuts.plist")

tell application "System Events"
    tell property list file thePropertyListFilePath
        set bPlistData to the value of property list item "shortcuts"
    end tell
end tell

writeToFile(bPlistData, bPlistDataShortcuts, true)


--  ## Handler ##

on writeToFile(theData, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)
    try
        set theFile to theFile as string
        if theFile contains "/" then
            set theOpenedFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        else
            set theOpenedFile to open for access file theFile with write permission
        end if
        if overwriteExistingContent is true then set eof of theOpenedFile to 0
        write theData to theOpenedFile starting at eof
        close access theOpenedFile
        return true
    on error
        try
            close access file theFile
        end try
        return false
    end try
end writeToFile
```

### Back in **Terminal**

```zsh
cd ..
plutil -convert xml1 divvy.shortcuts.plist
open -e divvy.shortcuts.plist
```

<sup>• Hint: Copy and paste the *commands* into **Terminal**, then press: <kbd>enter</kbd></sup>

### In **TextEdit**

- Looking for `<key>keyComboCode</key>` followed by e.g. `<integer>37</integer>` where `37` represents the *key code* for `L` and change `37` to `1`, the *key code* for `S`.
- Save and close the *file*.

### Back in **Terminal**

```zsh
plutil -convert binary1 divvy.shortcuts.plist
defaults delete com.mizage.direct.Divvy 'shortcuts'
defaults write com.mizage.direct.Divvy 'shortcuts' -data "$(xxd -p 'divvy.shortcuts.plist' | tr -d '\n')"
rm divvy.shortcuts.plist
```

<sup>• Hint: Copy and paste the *commands* into **Terminal**, then press: <kbd>enter</kbd></sup>

### Finishing up

Now reboot the **Mac** and one will be all set and ready to go, happily using a single character non-global *keyboard shortcut* in **Divvy**, that one could not assign from the *preferences* in **Divvy**.

---

**Notes:**

While I wrote the directions in mind to use all **macOS** native *applications/command line utilities*, nonetheless I highly recommend using an *editor* that provides *syntactical highlighting* to edit the **XML Plist data**. [**BBEdit**](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) is what I used.

While this is an example where only one user created single character *keyboard shortcut* was created and subsequently edited, nonetheless, keep in mind the *hierarchical XML structure* for each user created single character *keyboard shortcut* and be sure you are editing the correct one.

This was all done in virtual machines and and such there are no guaranties expressed or implied that the single character non-global *keyboard shortcuts* edited as described herein will be free of conflict on physical hardware. At this time I am unable to test on physical hardware.

<sup>I am not affiliated with the developer of BBEdit, just a satisfied user of the product.</sup>

Comment: I've tried changing `.plist` but when launching the app the file is overwritten somehow. I tried placing `keyComboCode` = `3` which is letter `F` but no luck.

Comment: @Mateusz Szlosek, I am currently writing up addition information for editing the `.plist` _file_, however I can assure you it is doable and works if done correctly.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Can't wait to see that :) Maybe I have to reboot the machine in order to make that file persist ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Mateusz Szlosek, One can not use _alpha characters_ in the `.plist` _file_ for the `keyComboCode` _key_, they must be `Key Code` _integers_ and one must exit **Divvy**, then make the modifications and then must reboot, as I've mentioned in my comments and answer thus far.

Comment: Yea, I've used `3` which should be letter `F`, and Divvy was closed. But I haven't rebooted and maybe this is the reason why the file was overwritten when I opened Divvy again.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this! Confirmed that I can import the .plist file from another machine and get the Divvy shortcuts working the way that I expect. Do you think I could do the same for 1Password (cmd+\)?

Comment: Yep will do. Do you happen to know if the same or a similar trick would work for 1Password? Historically they've tried to reserve cmd + backslash but that's also reserved in Monterey.

Comment: @Kevin Burke, RE: "Do you happen to know if the same or a similar trick would work for 1Password?" --  As I do not have or use it, no I can't say for sure, however, you certainly can try to employ the same methods as described in this answer. I'll check out the app tomorrow and see but you need to provide more information and where you are trying to assign the _keyboard shortcut_ etc.

Comment: Inside the 1Password app, on the "General" page of the app's Preferences, there's an input field to assign a shortcut to bring up the "1Password Mini" application

Comment: You write `To resolve your issue the obvious answer is to use a different single character keyboard shortcut, as non-global, or use in conjunction with modifier keys.`. The key combo I used so far is Option+ left/right arrow. So, I actually do use a modifier key but still have the exact same problem